# Reverse Values in an Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to understand this code that I found online, I just started learning to program with arrays which have saved me a lot of lines of code, but I do not understand this code at all

```
// C++ Program to reverse an array

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input[500], output[500], count, i;

    cout << "Enter number of elements in array\n";
    cin >> count;

    cout << "Enter " << count << " numbers \n";

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cin >> input[i];
    }

    // Copy numbers from inputArray to outputArray in
    // reverse order
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        output[i] = input[count - i - 1];
    }
    // Print Reversed array
    cout << "Reversed Array\n";
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << output[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The part where it says that it copies the input array to output array in reverse really confuses me, I do not understand how it reverts the values.

```
for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
    output[i] = input[count-i-1];
}
```

Could anyone explain me how that part works?

Comment: That bit should just be using `std::copy` with `rbegin`. Why do so many people program like `algorithm` does not exist?

Comment: The loop is assigning values to `output` starting at index `0` and incrementing.  The values being assigned are coming from `input` starting at index `count - i - 1` and decrementing which goes `count - 1`, `count - 2`, `count - 3` and so forth. So `output[0] = input[count-1]`, `output[1] = input[count-2]`, etc.

Comment: Off topic: Watch the fun that comes from entering, say, 1000 for count.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl A lot of people ask homework help here, When i took my c++ classes I wasn't allowed to use: 
1.) Anything not covered at class
2.) No STL/Algorithms unless explicitly stated otherwise
3.) Unreadable 'hacks' (RegEx type things)

Comment: All of which should be stated in the question, @OmarMartinez . Otherwise the answers will tend to the most logical for non-toy code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl far before that one should address the statement "I just started learning to programm with arrays *which have saved me a lot of lines of code*"...

Comment: @Omar Martinez fair enough. Personally I never attended any "official schooling" - just learned "on the job" for the past 25years or so. But I still find it annoying that people don't research (and use) the basics.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Wouldn't it be easier to use [`std::reverse_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy)

Comment: @Blastfurnace probably

Comment: @JesperJuhl I Agree, people should take more time to research before asking, and should explicitly state what any limitations are.

Answer (score 3):

It just takes data from input array but starts from end and puts them in output array. Lets say you have array of 10 items. Then you can write it like this:

```
output[0] = input[10-0-1]
output[1] = input[10-1-1]
```

You might wonder why the -1 at the end. It is because arrays in C++ are indexed from 0. So if you want 10th element, you need to subtract one from the array size.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a small array of 5 elements

```
input  = 1,2,3,4,5 output = 5,4,3,2,1 count = 5
Breaking down the copy loop

i=0 1st element output[1-1] = input[5-1] -> -1 since arrays are zero indexed 
i=1 2nd element output[2-1] = input[4-1]  
..........
.......... 
i=4 5th element output[5-1] = input[1-1]

Now to generalize this we can say 
output[i] = input[(count-1) -i] For all  i >=0 and i < count
```

Hope this helps in decoding `output[i] = input[count-i-1];`

Answer (score 0):

First of all , understand the fact that (count-1) is the index number of the last element in the original array.
Now [(count-1)-i] becomes the index of the elements of the array following the reverse order. Therefore, when we loop the value of i from 0 to count, it starts storing the value from the end. 
NOTE : The sum of i and [(count-1)-i] always gives (count-1) as the answer which is the key to store the number in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to reverse array values one of them which you mention it in your program by manipulating array indexes:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     output[i] = input[count - i - 1];
}
```

you can break it down in more detailed way to understand it well

Consider you have this array as example:

```
input = [1, 4, 5, 8, 0]
```

number of its elements `5` so `count = 5`

when you loop over it

in order to get the last index of `input[]` array from `i = 0`

you can use formula: `count - i -1`

`count -1` is the last element index in input array because array index begin from 0 in C++.

then `count -1 - i` : you subtract index `i` to reverse order of elements in input array.

if you try first index `i = 0`:

```
5 - 1 - 0 = 4
```

so index will be : `input[4]` **>>** `0`

as you see now you get the last element `0` from `i = 0` in the for loop

now output array should be : `output[0] = input[4]`

you put last element of input to first element in output

second index `i = 1`:

```
5 - 1 - 1 = 3
```

index of input will be : `input[3]` **>>** `8`

output array should be : `output[1] = input[3]`

now output array first two elements is actually last two elements of input array.

you can summarize how it works as following:

```
input[i] 1  4  5  8  0                output[i]  0
i        ^0          ^ 5 - 1 - 0      i          0

input[i] 1  4  5  8  0                output[i]  0  8
i           ^1    ^ 5 - 1 - 1         i          0  1

input[i] 1  4  5  8  0                output[i]  0  8  5
i              ^2 = 5 - 1 - 2         i          0  1  2

input[i] 1   4   5   8  0             output[i]  0  8  5  4 
i            ^5-1-3  ^3               i          0  1  2  3

input[i] 1   4   5   8  0             output[i]  0  8  5  4  1 
i        ^5-1-4         ^4            i          0  1  2  3  4
```